# About connecting multiple noun adjuncts

Tags: adjuncts

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct#English) Wikipedia article states:

> Noun adjuncts can also be strung together in a longer sequence preceding the final noun, with each added noun modifying the noun which follows it, in effect creating a multiple-word noun adjunct which modifies the **following** noun.

It says *following* and not *final* noun. Does that mean if we had a construct like :

> A B C final word.

, where A, B and C are noun adjuncts, then all of the following are true:

A modifies B,

[ A and B ] modifies C,

[ A and B and C ] modifies the final word.

.

Comment: It is difficult to say without seeing specific examples. Often, the last two words are nouns that can be restated with an of: treaty provisions=provisions of the treaty, where the noun treaty is used adjectivally. So....

Comment: *Can* it be? Yes. *Will* it be? Not always. As mentioned, you have to provide context.

Comment: If we take for example *Cable News Network*, *Cable* would qualify *News* and *Cable News*  would collectively qualify *Network*, isn'it?